# Text positioned over image looks different in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, image, text, responsive-design

I'm trying to keep the word "SOLD" in the top-right corner of the image, in the same location no matter the user's screen size/browser. It works fine in Chrome but when I use Internet Explorer, the "SOLD" is shown in a completely different place at 1440px width than it is shown on my Chrome browser at 1440px.

I have an unordered list with a list item containing a few divs, and an image. You can see my site [here](http://testsite24.byethost17.com/temp/index.html)

For the list items I want to display "SOLD", the list item code looks like this:

```
<li class="list__item">
            <figure class="list__item__inner">
     <a class="divLink" href="http://www.Demo">
            <img src="http://media-cdn.tripadvisor.com/media/photo-o/01/ca/eb/48/clenahoo-house.jpg" alt="" />
             <div class="caption">SOLD</div>
             <div class="titlebox">Demo</div>
             <div class="locationbox">Demo</div>
            <div class="pricebox">Demo Demo</div>
     </a>
        </li>
```

.

You can see I use a class called "caption" to display SOLD currently. This element's CSS is:

.

```
.list__item .caption    {
    position: absolute;
    width: 20%;
    height: 10%;
    top: 6%;
    left: 56%;
    font-size: 3.3vw;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: red;
    }
```

The font-size is responsive by using 'vw', but in Internet Explorer once the viewport reaches about 1,000px wide the SOLD text sticks outside the image, but this doesn't happen at the same viewport width in Chrome.

How do I fix this? thanks a lot!!

Comment: Without investigating it too much, my guess would be that it is because you are using viewport units, which are only partially supported in IE: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: Hmm... can you offer a solution if that's the case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For me, the SOLD text sticks outside the image on any browser when the viewport becomes wide: Chrome, IE and Firefox. You could use `em` instead of `vw`, and use media queries to change the font size for different viewports. And `font-size: 3.3em;` works nicely on wide viewports.

For narrower viewports, you can use media queries:

```
@media (max-width: 960px) {
 .list__item .caption    {
    font-size: 2em;
}

@media (max-width: 480px) {
 .list__item .caption    {
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

Don't try to make your page looks the same in every browser, at every viewport.

Comment: I've applied the changes, but the text still overhangs the right side of the image in Chrome and IE, my viewport size is 1440x775 for Chrome, and 1694 × 860 for IE. The page source of my site (link above) shows I'm using 'em' now, and added the queries, but SOLD still doesn't fit in the top-right corner for me. Confused..

Comment: You have a lot of media queries and too many closing curly braces, so only the 960px media query is kicking in. Removing the extra  curly braces seems to help. Try http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ to help you find them. Now 3.3em looks too large - try 2.3em instead, and smaller fonts for smaller viewports. You might need more media queries to get the page closer to pixel-perfect in every browser (which as I said, I shouldn't try to achieve anyway.)

Comment: Thank you Michael, I'll now tweak it to my liking. I appreciate your detailed support, take care.